# Grav CMS: how to show/hide parts of the page depending on conditions?

Tags: twig, grav

The Grav's documentation clearly describes [how a whole page or a folder could be hidden from unregistered users](https://learn.getgrav.org/cookbook/general-recipes#create-a-private-area). It also describes [how a whole page could be seen only by particular user groups](https://learn.getgrav.org/cookbook/general-recipes#use-group-based-permissions).

But what about *pieces of a page*, let's say, some links or a private info I want to show on some conditions?

Ok, for registered users I found a snippet at [Login plugin docs](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-login#logout):

```
{% if grav.user.authenticated %}
    content for registered users goes here
{% endif %}
```

But going wider - **how can I show/hide *pieces* of a particular page depending on some custom logic in PHP code**, i.e. not necessarily user related?

I'm thinking about a twig/shortcode plugin, something like:

```
{% if some.custom.condition.or.PHP.function %}
   hidden content goes here
{% endif %}
```

or

```
[hidden_if_something] hidden content goes here [/hidden_if_something]
```

But not sure how exactly this should be implemented. So working examples would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a recipe in the Grav documentation [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/cookbook/plugin-recipes#output-some-php-code-result-in-a-twig-template). This provides an example of how to render the output of a PHP code result in a twig template.

In the example they create a plugin, and implement a twig extension providing access to a php function. They can then simply call that php function like in a twig template.

```
{{ example() }}
```

Following that example, you can implement whatever logic you would like in php, and call the function in a twig if statement.

```
{% if example() == true %}
   your conditional output
{% endif %
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have read the docs more carefully :)